# jdbc mysql loginTimeout not working

Tags: java, jdbc

Can someone please explain why the following program timeout after 3 seconds where as I set it to do so after
12 seconds. I deliberately turned off mysql server to test this scenario where mysql server is unreachable.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

/**
 *
 * @author dhd
 */
public class TestMysql {

    static Thread trd;

    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        keepTrack();
        try {
            DriverManager.setLoginTimeout(12);
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/driving", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            trd.stop();
        }
    }

    public static void keepTrack() {
        trd = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 1;
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }
        });
        trd.start();
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
run:
1
2
3
Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds).
```

Run from netbeans. Before asking why i need this please answer first please. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the MySQL server is not running the connection does not time out; the operating system replies with a "connection refused" error immediately. To make the connection time out one thing you can do is configure a fire wall to drop all packets arriving to the MySQL port.

Comment: joni, mysql is not running in this case, no contact whatsoever with mysql, what i want is for the connection to keep trying to connect for 12 seconds before giving up, not 3 seconds. why? because in those 12 seconds mysql server might come back online and will now be reachable. hope i made it clear. we do not have mysql running yet so we cant talk about packets from mysql where as we cant even contact mysql

Comment: The login timeout means "stop trying to log in if server does not reply", not "keep retrying if there's an error".

Comment: still, i set 12 seconds for "stop trying to log in if server does not reply", but it does not obey

Comment: The server replies immediately with a "connection refused" error, like I wrote above.

Comment: ok joni thanks i see i am lacking knowledge but i need to trouble u. the thing i do not want is that "immediately". yes i understand it replies immediately. is there no way to tell the connection not to give up trying to contact the server before x seconds. i understand what login timeout is for, is there no opposite? when i read api for setLoginTimeout it tells me that is the maximum seconds. so what i want is minimum seconds.

Comment: I think you have to retry from application code, using a loop. A connection pool library like Apache dbcp would have this functionality built-in.

Comment: The MySQL JDBC driver has `autoReconnect` and `maxReconnects` options. I don't know if they affect also the initial connection, or if they only re-establish a dropped connection. See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html